# Spring boot RestController PathVariable string has quotation marks appended

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am using a spring boot restcontroller that has a method with requestmapping of GET and it takes a string parameter. Parameter has to be mapped from the URL PathVariable such /method/{param}.

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
RequestMapping(value = "/method/{param}", method = 
RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity findByName(@PathVariable String param){


logger.info(param);// this log has &#34; before and after the string

String p  = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(param);

logger.info(p); 


 ... 
 }
```

HTTP Request

```
    GET /SampleDataService/method/vanilla HTTP/1.1
    Host: localhost:8080
    Connection: keep-alive
    Pragma: no-cache
    Cache-Control: no-cache
    Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1    
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

I do get the value param but it has the html escaped quotation marks appended to it.

For eg, if I call `/method/vanilla` I get `&#34;vanilla&#34;`

Right now I am using `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(param)` and then replacing the quotes with empty string.
But I want to know if there is some spring boot configuration that can prevent extra quotes in string PathVariables.

Comment: have you trie with `@PathVariable("param")`?

Comment: I did, since the name matches in RequestMapping and the method signature, it is not required

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please provide a [mcve]. (And show us the HTTP request dump.)

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis , I have added more detail as requested

Comment: What does your boot configuration look like? Anything outside the defaults? Tomcat? Jetty?

Comment: I am using spring-boot-starter-parent and wildfly

Comment: Maybe wildfly is adding them for some reason. This isn't a Spring Boot issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thank you, will look in to that.

Answer (score -1):

In url having multiple parameters

```
@RequestMapping(value="/method/{param:.+}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity findByName(@PathVariable("param")String param){
 ....
}
```

Comment: yes, param inside the method comes as `&#34;test&#34;` . I called `/method/test`